# How do I break out of the page width constraints

Tags: html, css

Pretty straight forward, I want the ASP.NET page to take up the full width of the screen. 100% is NOT 100%, I've tried many suggestions and all have failed. I am sure this is a simple line of code, but I just don't seem to be hitting it.

If you need snippets of code, let me know, but I don't think it's going to help.

Thanks.

[image]

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="mytestsite.com.Site1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title><%: Page.Title %></title>

<webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css"/>
<link   href="~/Content/bootstrap.css"      type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" type="text/js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"        type="text/js"></script>
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
</head>
<body style="resize:both; margin:0%; height:100%; width:100%;">
<form runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" ScriptMode="Release" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true">
<Scripts>
<%--Framework Scripts--%>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" Path="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
            <%--Site Scripts--%>
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Return to My Test Site Home</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Bin Shredding - Overview</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Facility Questionnaire</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Bin Shredding FAQ</a></li>
                </ul>
                <p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My Test Site</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

</form>
```

DOM Capture, as per the request.

[image]

Comment: This is nothing to do with ASP.NET. This is a HTML/CSS question. Please post your **rendered** markup.

Comment: You wrote that you have "tried many suggestions" without saying what they actually were.

Comment: Suggestions include:
1) Setting body style to "margin:0%; height:100%; width:100%;" within site.master
2) Setting the items in another DIV to break out of the parent container.
3) Some javascript in the bootstrap.css

Comment: This is for an .aspx page. I don't see any HTML/CSS items anywhere in the project. Are you referring to site.master?

Comment: Thanks. Posted Master Page content.

Comment: you can create custom css and override some bootstrap.css tags.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with ASP.NET, there's some CSS that's doing this. We aren't going to find this CSS, because it's on your machine. Hit F12 and go inspect your DOM.

Comment: IE is the company standard, I stick with what most everyone is using.

Comment: Not working in Chrome either, fyi.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. We can't see anything from a screenshot of a collapsed DOM. Inspect it **yourself**, inspect the relevant element properties (hint: width).

Comment: This had nothing to do with DOM, so it wouldn't have mattered anyway. Besides, the question was general and should have been a homogeneous solution, which was provided below. This had nothing to do with what i had coded, but rather how to get around these default settings (which everyone has with a new ASP.NET page using bootstrap).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using bootstrap. In the html markup you have a div with a class container. If you look into the bootstrap css you will see that there is a style attached to that which indicates a max width, maybe something like 1170px or something. There have been various values and/or it is possible to customize that when downloading the bootstrap package.

The easiest way to change that is to change the container class to `container-fluid`. It is also possible to edit the css files and change them, but it is complex because there are many different media queries where the max-width for `.container` are defined.

Comment: I don't appreciate whoever thumbs down'd my question, as there is nothing I could find after hours of research pertaining to this question. But, despite the pushback from the community, you sir, have answered my question. 1 million internets for you, good sir!

Comment: You're welcome. There are a lot of features and things in bootstrap. Check out the basics here http://getbootstrap.com/css/ and all the other bits you can use in the components http://getbootstrap.com/components/. Those two sections were the most useful to me when I was getting started.

Comment: Many thanks, I have only been playing with modifying things from bootswatch at this point.